# Setting completion-styles with read-multiple-choice

Tags: read

Am playing with `read-multiple-choice` to set `completion-styles`.  Originally had `(nth 1 sentry)` but with `'(basic substring)`, it will only pick up `substring`.  Thus I can instead call `(setq completion-styles sentry)`.

I cannot understand the error when making a selection.

```
(error "Invalid completion style 111")
```

Am I doing this right?  Can I improve on the `read-multiple-choice` part?

```
(defun sentry (sentry)
  "Sets minibuffer completion style."

  (interactive
   (let ( (stysq '((?o '(orderless) "orderless")
                   (?b '(basic substring) "substring")
                   (?p '(partial-completion) "partial")
                   (?f '(flex) "flex")
                   (?i '(initials) "initials"))) )
           (read-multiple-choice "Sentry: " stysq)))

  (setq completion-styles (nth 1 sentry)))
```

Comment: Welcome back Mr. volatile identity. I still would advise you to try to read the documentation more carefully, and also to read once or twice more at least [the 'Lists' section of the elisp reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lists.html)...

Comment: The funny thing is the generic descriptions that give no real help.  It seems to me that the writers go to great lengths not to write useful examples and to avoid them completely.

Comment: There is an example in the docstring of `read-multiple-choice`. We have told you multiple times already that `interactive` expects a list. Also, we have provided multiple examples of how to use `pcase`. When solving these problems, you should try to become creative with the options you know about. Try to find the essence of what you are trying to achieve with each step.

Comment: Looks as if it would be better to use strings `(?o "orderless" "Use orderless completion.")`.

Comment: Wouldn't the selection pass a list?  You seem to suggest that I should call `(list` after the `interactive` clause.  Would that not produce a list of lists?

Comment: Well I think the description strings are a little redundant in this case. But you can add them if you like... I am just saying that interactive expects a list, so in the first version I added `list`. In the current version, `alist-get` (on a list, not a cons) makes sure that a list gets passed to interactive.

Comment: Right.  But the suggested approach is not to use `'(orderless)` but use `"orderless"` for the user selection.

Comment: I don't understand your last question (if it was a question)... but please just look at the answer and try to understand it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `interactive` expects a list as its argument.
You can first get the choice and then get the value in a list using `alist-get` as the elements of choices are lists (not cons). Finally, you can read the string in value using `read`:

```lisp
(defun sentry (sentry)
  "Sets minibuffer completion style."
  (interactive
   (let ((choices '((?o "(orderless)")
                    (?b "(basic substring)")
                    (?p "(partial-completion)")
                    (?f "(flex)")
                    (?i "(initials)"))))

     (alist-get (car (read-multiple-choice "Sentry: " choices))
                choices)))
  (message "`completion-style' set to %s"
           (setq completion-styles (read sentry))))
```

Comment: You search for  `?o` to pick out the `"(orderless)"` entry.  Thought to use `cadr` at first.

Comment: Indeed, I am using `alist-get` to get the value from an alist. I think you know `alist-get` already, so why use `cadr`? If you do not know alist-get... then again... read [the `Lists` section of the elisp reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lists.html).

Comment: I know it.  Do people prefer that, rather than `cadr`?

Comment: I don't know. What do you prefer?